# I need a 5 digit string which is incremented automatic (A0001 - Z9999) in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want auto-incremented string to generate project code which will start from A0001 - A9999 then it should start from B0001 accordingly till Z9999.

Comment: Just create a purely numeric auto-incrementing column, and then add a computed column that does this *formatting* to produce the mixed alpha-numeric ID you want to show to users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I'd do instead:

```
create table T (
    _RealID int IDENTITY(1,1) not null,
    ID as
         CHAR(ASCII('A') + _RealID / 10000) +
         RIGHT('0000' + CONVERT(varchar(4),_RealID % 10000),4),
    OtherColumns varchar(10) not null
)
```

My convention is that columns that start with a `_` are not intended to be used by users/applications. If it's important enough to hide, I'll instead create a `_T` table with the above definition and then a `T` view which only selects the columns without the `_` prefix. users/applications are then only given access to the view.

Comment: _RealID = 10000 -> ID = B0000

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE StringId (
    [id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(0,1) CONSTRAINT [PK_StringId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    CONSTRAINT CK_StringId_id CHECK ([id] >= 0 AND [id] <= 259973), -- 26 * 9999-1
    [StringId] as CHAR(ASCII('A') + [id] / 9999) + RIGHT(CAST( 10000 + [id] % 9999 + 1 as varchar(5)),4) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    TestValue int NULL);

INSERT INTO StringId (TestValue)
    Values (12345),(23456),(34567);

SElECT * FROM [StringId];
```